# blogdown ghostwriter doesn't render Rmarkdown plot on netlify

Tags: r-markdown, hugo, blogdown, netlify

In the "Hello R Markdown" post included in the blogdown ghostwriter theme, the pie chart renders in Rstudio viewer, but not when deployed on Netlify. Rstudio view:  [image: Rstudio view]  [Netlify view](https://painter-resource-65644.netlify.com/2015/07/23/2015-07-23-r-rmarkdown/)  Deployed with Hugo  version 0.27.1.  [GitHub](https://github.com/johnbwilliams/openemr-ghost-blog)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should commit the `static/` folder in GIT, as mentioned in [Section C.6](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/version-control.html) in the **blogdown** book.

> As we mentioned in Section C.4, R plots will be copied to `static/`, so you may see new files in GIT after you render an Rmd file that has graphics output. You need to add and commit these new files in GIT, because the website will use them.

Comment: @JohnWilliams If it works, please accept the answer.

Comment: In case of this particular theme, I had .gitignore file created under the /static, removing/modifying it solved the problem.